# 'user ... is not allowed to execute .... as root on ... ' - even with SUDO privileges but not sure why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, password, sudo

I am in the processing of installing singularity using the terminal on my Linux Mint computer (Ubuntu).

I have the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The computer then asks me to enter my password:

```
[sudo] password for user:
```

When I enter my password, the computer gives me the error:

```
user emre is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get udpate' as root on spiers06
```

However, I have checked that I have SUDO privileges, which my linux terminal confirms that I do, so I am unsure as to why the computer may be giving me this error.

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

Comment: Well, you probably should run `sudo -l` and compare with whatever user, command and machine is listed in the message `sudo` gives you...

Comment: @Tomek when I run that command it says: 'user .. may run the following commands on ...: (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/checkAPT.py' - does this mean that I am only allowed to run one command on the linux terminal?

Comment: Yes. But it may in turn run `apt` as root which should allow you at least some apt operations. Unfortunately I am not an expert on apt, I am on rpm based distro...

Comment: ok thanks for confirming!